# how to get number of items in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

In my program i took a listbox, in this listbox I added number of items.

Now I want to know how to get number of listbox items & show number of items in a textbox. when number of items is not fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's say your listbox is called ListBox1 and textbox is TextBox1. Then the code you need is

```
TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Of course knowing your platform (WinForms, WebForms, Html etc.) would help a lot for a more accurate answer.

Comment: With the ASP.Net tag, I am pretty sure this is WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present an answer for the people who uses WPF.

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parts}">                   
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Content="{Binding CurrentPart, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Parts.Count}"                           
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```